# VSCode erroneous comment repeating behavior

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, comments

I have uninstalled 2 extensions (Auto Comment Blocks and Document This) that I thought they could be responsible, also I deleted the node_modules folder and setup the javascript (three.js) working folder again for intellisence/autocomplete (via types) and still the problem remains.

Here is before and after selecting a variable.
Is there a way to fix this extremely idiotic behavior?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, although I have the problem for a long time, I instinctively found the answer just after I posted the question:

I put my only two (custom) source files main.js and shaders.js in a 'src' folder, then edited the jsconfig.json file and I changed the exclude reference, in order to exlude all other *.js files in the root folder and added the include.
Now jsdoc comment repeating stopped completely, and as a bonus, intellisence works far better!

from:

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

to:

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "*.js"
  ]
  "include": [
        "src/*.js"
  ]
```

**EDIT**: Or include alone, as Sumomo suggested in the comments.

Comment: Nice, mine looks like `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "ES2018"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}` I think having an include means everything else is excluded, you may want to verify that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried leaving only include and it works, thanks, I did a couple of quick tests and it seems to exclude everything else, despite the word "include" doesn't imply that. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy/paste the code as well as screen-shot I can see what happens in my install.

- Did you restart after un-installing the extensions?
- Have you run vs code with all extensions disabled? `code --disable-extensions`
- I assume you are using the latest official version?
- Do you have typescript checking enabled?